# Could not AOT the assembly with FSharp.Core

Tags: azure, azure-devops, f#, xamarin.ios

I receive the following release build error:

> MTOUCH : error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly
> .../MyCustomerProject.IOS/obj/iPhone/Release/mtouch-cache/3-Build/FSharp.Core.dll'
> [.../MyCustomerProject.IOS/MyCustomerProject.IOS.csproj]

**Note:**

I'm able to run this app on the iPhone simulator.

However, the Azure Devops Build fails.

Comment: there are many, many posts on SO and elsewhere about MT3001 issues - what have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't know what to try in regards to FSharp support.
I didn't see a solution for how it relates to FSharp.

Comment: Try posting in https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/10231
But with useful information, including anything to help identify the change that stopped the build from working.

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded the FSharp.Core library version number.